# Show virtual image while tracking hand

Tags: c++, opencv, virtual-reality

How can we display a virtual image on our hand while real time tracking of our hand through camera using OpenCV with C++. I wanted the code so that whenever we place our hand in front of camera it displays a virtual image over our hand.

Comment: What have you already tried? I believe people won't just give you a full code to solve your problem. I suggest you trying to do a bit more research. If you get specific errors when trying some code, then you can ask here. Stack Overflow is not a suited place to ask for guides and directions (in most cases I'd say).

Answer (score 0):

You can search for "code examples for hand-tracking with OpenCV"; mean-shift algorithm is particularly good. Once you find an example and get it to run or produce bugs, please edit the question with those info so that we can give more specific answers.